# Content Security Policy (CSP) in Next.js - how to pass it to full application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, content-security-policy

I'm using Next.js and a separate express backend in a project, and want to implement a Content Security Policy (CSP), with nonces as I have understood this is best practice.

According to next.js documentation, I have created a middleware.js file according to this link: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/content-security-policy

So far, so good.

However, I now want to access this "nonce" somewhere in the application where it applies for all scripts. My thinking has been to access it in the _document, and pass the nonce to the NextScript. I've been trying to get access to the headers in the _document file, but none of my tested approaches work (getServerSideProps/getStaticProps). How do I get access to this nonce? And is it sufficient to add it to the  ?

My _document looks like this

```
// Approach 1 which does not work
// import { headers } from "next/headers";
// Approach 1 which does not work

export default function Document() {

  // Approach 1 which does not work
  // const nonce = headers().get("x-nonce");
  // console.log(nonce);
  // Approach 1 which does not work

  return (
    <Html>
      <Head>
        <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Public+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}

// example 2, running getSeriverside props - it seems it does not happen?
export async function getServerSideProps({ req }) {
  try {
    console.log(req);
    // this is not logging anywhere...

    return {
      props: { connect: "example fuccess" },
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      props: { connect: "example fail" },
    };
  }
}

// example 3, running getStaticProps - also does not fire
export async function getStaticProps({ req }) {
  try {
    console.log(req);
    // this is not logging anywhere...

    return {
      props: { connect: "example fuccess" },
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      props: { connect: "example fail" },
    };
  }
}
```

Edit, thanks to answers, this is one way to get good scores:

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

export default function Document() {
  const nonce = Buffer.from(crypto.randomUUID()).toString("base64");
  const cspHeader = `
  default-src 'self' https://api.YOURDOMAIN.io ;
  script-src 'self' 'nonce-${nonce}' https://api.YOURDOMAIN.io;

  style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline' ;
  
  img-src 'self' blob: data:;
  font-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com;
  object-src 'none';
  base-uri 'self';
  form-action 'self';
  block-all-mixed-content;
  upgrade-insecure-requests;
`;

  //  style-src 'self'  'nonce-${nonce}';

  return (
    <Html>
      <Head nonce={nonce}>
        {process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" && (
          <meta property="csp-nonce" content={nonce} />
        )}
        {process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" && (
          <meta httpEquiv="Content-Security-Policy" content={cspHeader} />
        )}
        <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Public+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript nonce={nonce} />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it:

- Generate CSP header insider middleware
- Set `x-nonce` hader inside middleware so we can easily access the nonce in `_document` and `_app`
- Access nonce in `_document` by reading it from `x-nonce` header and set the nonce to NextScript and anywhere needed.
- Access the nonce in `_app` and use it wherever needed.

Code example:

So first we have the middleware (example from https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/content-security-policy):

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request) {
  const nonce = Buffer.from(crypto.randomUUID()).toString("base64");
  const cspHeader = `
    default-src 'self';
    script-src 'self' 'nonce-${nonce}' 'strict-dynamic';
    style-src 'self' 'nonce-${nonce}';
    img-src 'self' blob: data:;
    font-src 'self';
    object-src 'none';
    base-uri 'self';
    form-action 'self';
    frame-ancestors 'none';
    block-all-mixed-content;
    upgrade-insecure-requests;
`;

  const requestHeaders = new Headers();
  requestHeaders.set("x-nonce", nonce);
  requestHeaders.set(
    "Content-Security-Policy",
    // Replace newline characters and spaces
    cspHeader.replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ").trim()
  );

  return NextResponse.next({
    headers: requestHeaders,
    request: {
      headers: requestHeaders,
    },
  });
}
```

Then we access nonce in _document.js

```
import NextDocument, { Head, NextScript, Main, Html } from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends NextDocument {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    // Read the nonce from response headers so we can access it in Document render function
    const nonce = ctx.res.getHeader("x-nonce");
    return {
      ...(await NextDocument.getInitialProps(ctx)),
      nonce,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { nonce } = this.props;

    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head nonce={nonce} />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

Then we also need to access it in _app so you can pass it to MUI. How that is done depends on how you're styling your MUI components, since there's so many different ways. Refer to MUI documentation on how to use nonce.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps, nonce }) {
  // Nonce prop will only be available on first render
  const [cachedNonce] = useState(nonce);
  console.log(cachedNonce);
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

App.getInitialProps = async ({ ctx }) => {
  const nonce = ctx.res.getHeader("x-nonce");
  return {
    nonce,
  };
};
```

The reason we can't set the `x-nonce` header inside _document is that during SSR `App.getInitialProps` is ran before `Document.getInitialProps`.

Comment: I'm a little bit puzzled about this approach, how do I make sure that the nonce is secret and only used for each request?

Comment: The Document function is executed on every page load, so if you generate the nonce inside it, it will be unique for each request.

Comment: I added sample code

Comment: Thanks for that! I have used you logic and it works to great extent, however, my Material UI components (which are used a lot) does not work. Do you understand how to pass the nonce also to these components? I really want to avoid "using "unsafe-inline" for style-src. I've updates the example above.

Comment: Updated the answer to include on how to access nonce in _app.